# angularJS module bootstrap issues angular-appinsights

Tags: angularjs, azure-application-insights

Hoping someone can help me out here...  We are new to angularJS but have committed to using it on an upcoming project.  One of the things we want to get in place from the start is app feature usage monitoring and we are planning to use Microsoft's Application Insights to do that.  I was very happy to discover that there is an angularJS module already built for working with app insights recommended on Microsoft's getting started page for App Insights [angular-appinsights](https://github.com/johnhidey/angular-appinsights).  Unfortunately we are having a very difficult time bootstrapping this module.

Pretty sure we are the problem here, I feel that if we knew a little more about angularJS we could figure this out but since we are just cutting our teeth on it I am turning to SO for help!

So here is the portion of index.html where we are loading all of our scripts:

```
    <!-- 3rd party libraries -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/angular-local-storage.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/loading-bar.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/angular-appinsights.js"></script>
<!-- Load app main script -->
<script src="app/app.js"></script>
```

Here is the relevant portion of app.js where everything is wired up:

```
var app = angular.module('MTCAPITester', ['ngRoute', 'LocalStorageModule', 'angular-loading-bar','angular-appinsights']);
```

app.config(['$routeProvider','insightsProvider',function ($routeProvider,insightsProvider) {

```
$routeProvider.when("/home", {
    controller: "homeController",
    templateUrl: "/app/views/home.html"
});

$routeProvider.when("/login", {
    controller: "loginController",
    templateUrl: "/app/views/login.html"
});

$routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: "/home" });

insightsProvider.start('our app insights key here');}]);
```

And here is the app insights javascript that you are supposed to put in the head tag of index.html:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var appInsights = window.appInsights || function (config) {
            function s(config) { t[config] = function () { var i = arguments; t.queue.push(function () { t[config].apply(t, i) }) } } var t = { config: config }, r = document, f = window, e = "script", o = r.createElement(e), i, u; for (o.src = config.url || "//az416426.vo.msecnd.net/scripts/a/ai.0.js", r.getElementsByTagName(e)[0].parentNode.appendChild(o), t.cookie = r.cookie, t.queue = [], i = ["Event", "Exception", "Metric", "PageView", "Trace"]; i.length;) s("track" + i.pop()); return config.disableExceptionTracking || (i = "onerror", s("_" + i), u = f[i], f[i] = function (config, r, f, e, o) { var s = u && u(config, r, f, e, o); return s !== !0 && t["_" + i](config, r, f, e, o), s }), t
        };

    window.appInsights = appInsights;
    </script>
```

Unfortunately we consistently get the ugly angular modulerr which I assume is telling me it can't bootstrap this module b/c if I remove the code related to this module everything works fine.

Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$injector/modulerr?p0=MTCAPITester&p1=Er…gleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.16%2Fangular.min.js%3A32%3A445)

Can anyone help me understand what we are missing here?  I don't quite understand where the reference to insightsProvider is coming into play as I don't have that defined anywhere and I don't see it defined in [his library](https://github.com/johnhidey/angular-appinsights) either.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated, this seems pretty straight forward but I am just not comfortable enough with angularJS at this point to understand where/why this is failing...

Comment: btw, we have downloaded his sample app and it works just fine.  So clearly this is an issue on our end, can't figure out why the way he wires it up works but ours doesn't...

Comment: insightsProvider is being created in his library with .provider('insights'. It uses some injector magic to deliver this to you as insightsProvider.

In the sample app, the angular version is 1.2.18, and you're using 1.2.16 - perhaps try updating angular? I don't see anything immediately wrong with what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks Sperr, actually I may have just figured it out, still testing but... I moved the MS provided javascript from the head tag of index.html into a .js file of its own and included it just below the include of application-insights.js (I noticed he had done it this way in his sample though his docs say to put it in head tag) and it looks like it is working now.

Comment: also thanks for the comment on the injector magic that is happening there, that is what I was trying to understand but I am good with magic as long as I know that is what is happening...

Comment: Great to hear it's working! My guess would be that the code in the tag may have run before angular was loading, causing problems. A tip for next time - if you use the non-minified version of angular.js while developing, you will get much more meaningful error messages.

Comment: Another great tip, thank you b/c the lack of meaningful error msgs has been a point of contention!

Answer (score 2):

Another issue I've found with 'angular-appinsights.js' is, If you are using the **ngRoute** directive in your angular application for routing, then you should be okay. But if you are using **ui.router** for routing/states then 'angular-appinsights.js' will not work correctly and will throw an error. I found a fix for this here [Angular-AppInsights – Unknown Provider – FIX](http://blog.devdivision.co.za/), and its quite simple. In the **.run** function of the angular-appinsights.js module, you will find $route is being injected. If you **remove $route** from being injected into that function, angular-appinsights will work.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the MS provided JS that they instruct you to put in the head tag of index.html was the source of the problem.  Sperr speculated that maybe it was run before angular was loading.  Solution to the problem was to pull that js out of the head tag and put it in its own .js file,  then include it below the reference to angular-appinsights.js.  With that change, everything is working great.